# Adjusting grid and tick marks on violin plot produced by vioplot package

Tags: r, plot

The following code will display a `vioplot` overlaid with a grid

```
dat <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
vioplot(dat, col = "yellow")
grid (NULL, lty = 6, col = "grey")
```

[image]

How would one remove the x-axis label of "1", its corresponding tick mark, and only display horizontal grid lines?

Adding the following does not work:

```
title(xlab="")
```

Comment: `vioplot(dat, col = "yellow", names=""); grid(NULL, lty = 6, col = "grey", nx=0)`

Comment: yes but a tick mark still remains \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the x-axis tick label and draw only horizontal gridlines as follows:

```
library(vioplot)

set.seed(2)
dat <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)

# Draw plot without x-axis tick label
vioplot(dat, col = "yellow", names="")

# Draw only horizontal grid lines
grid(NULL, lty = 6, col = "grey", nx=0)
```

It looks like the axis tick marks are hard-coded. However, you can modify the `vioplot` function itself to create an option to remove the tick marks. To get the function code, type `vioplot` in the console. Copy and paste the code into an R script and assign the function a new name, like `my_violin`. Somewhere inside `vioplot/my_violin` there's a call to the `axis` function to draw the x-axis. We just need to add a way to modify this call to `axis` so that we can decide whether or not to draw tick marks. To do that, add the following argument to the `my_violin` function declaration:

```
tick=TRUE
```

Then find the following line of code inside the `my_violin` function:

```
axis(1, at = at, label = label)
```

and change it to this:

```
axis(1, at = at, label = label, tick=tick)
```

Now, run the new function with `tick=FALSE`:

```
my_violin(dat, col = "yellow", names="", tick=FALSE)
grid(NULL, lty = 6, col = "grey", nx=0)
```

[image]

Here's a `ggplot2` approach to the same plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat=data.frame(y=dat), aes(x="", y=y)) +
  geom_violin(fill="yellow") + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=1:5, colour="grey40", linetype=4, size=0.3) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.05) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  labs(x="", y="")
```

[image]